# Update is not working in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Dont mind the security issues, this is just local testing, but when ever i click the update button none of the changes go through on the page or on the query and i get no erros.

```
<?php 

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test") or die("could not connect");

if (isset($_POST['update'])) { 

$updateQuery = (" UPDATE `test1` SET f_name = '$_POST[f_name]', l_name='$_POST[l_name]', email='$_POST[email]' WHERE id='$_POST[id]'");
mysqli_query($link, $updateQuery);


};


$query = ("SELECT * FROM `test1`");
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

echo "<table border=1
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Email</th> 
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<form method=post action=update.php>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=f_name value=" . $row['f_name'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=l_name value=" . $row['l_name'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=email value=" . $row['email'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=id value=" . $row['id'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=submit value=update" .  " </td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

?>

Comment: You are checking if the $_POST['update'] is set, but where is that input field?

Comment: @Pitchinnate no errors it just reverts back to what is already written in the database

Comment: @Benz the last input field is the update one

Comment: @Cesarg219 No it isn't, the name of the last field is submit ;)

Comment: @Cesarg219 - the last input field has a name of `submit`; it's _value_ is update, but you're looking for a field with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$updateQuery = ("UPDATE `test1` SET f_name = '{$_POST['f_name']}', l_name='{$_POST['l_name']}', email='{$_POST['email']}' WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'");
```

Also you can try echoing something inside your `if (isset($_POST['update'])) {` to make sure it is testing true.

Here is your problem:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'update') {
```

The name of the submit button is submit not update, the value is update.

Comment: when i tried this instead, it only allowed me to edit the last row on the table none of the other rows allowed me to change the information it didnt go through

Comment: That is because you don't have the `</form>` inside your loop.

Comment: Also none of your `<input>` have the closing `>` on them.

Answer (score 0):

change your form to

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<form method=post action=update.php>";
    echo "<input type=hidden name=update>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=f_name value=" . $row['f_name'] . " </td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=l_name value=" . $row['l_name'] . " </td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=email value=" . $row['email'] . " </td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=id value=" . $row['id'] . " </td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=submit value=update" .  " </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: only change to the database that went through was the last row all the other ones nothing happens

Comment: You have work on your update query and that depends what you want to achieve?

Comment: the idea is to have all the rows have information inside of them pulled from the database and allow me to write over them and send what i wrote to the database so when i refresh the page i can see my changes went through

Answer (score 0):

POST keys should be in quotes. Try this instead:

> $updateQuery = "UPDATE test1 SET f_name = ".$_POST['f_name'].", l_name=."$_POST['l_name'].", email=".$_POST['email']." WHERE id=".$_POST['id'];